# Are there any recommended filter types for passband frequencies near Nyquist?

Tags: filters, nyquist, bandpass, complex

Is there a recommended filter type for frequency bands near the Nyquist frequency?

I have been trying to design complex passband filter with passband $[0.8 ~~1]$ ( where $1$ corresponds to the normalized Nyquist frequency) and stopband $[-1 ~~0.7]$. Using an equiripple filter of order 30 under Matlab,

```
f = [-1 -0.9 -0.8 -0.7 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8  1];
a = [ zeros(1,length(f)-2) 1 1];

n = 30;

d = fdesign.arbmag('n,f,a',n,f,a); 
hd = design(d,'equiripple'); 
fvtool(hd)`
```

I get the following frequency response,

[image]

To be a bit more specific, I would like to know if it is possible to extend the passband all the way up to the normalized frequency $1$. As we can see in the figure above, the frequency response of the filter begins to decrease above approximately $0.97$-ish.

Comment: If you are implementing a filter whose amplitude response is not symmetric around $f = 0$, then you must be implementing it for complex-valued signals.  If you are using complex-valued signals, then the Nyquist frequency is $2 \pi \mathrm{radian/sample}$.  I'm Android #1, and Spock just whispered in my ear "logic is a little tweeting bird".  So before my head start's smoking -- what's _really_ going on here?

Comment: And note that in the $z$ domain, $f = \pi \mathrm{radian / sample}$ is congruent with $f = -\pi \mathrm{radian / sample}$ (your "1 * Nyquist" and "-1 * Nyquist").  So the filter _must_ show significant attenuation around $f = \pi \mathrm{radian / sample}$, because you're asking for a stopband that starts _at that exact frequency_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the filter is circular across the Nyquist boundary, and so the requirement as given has no transition band. Filter complexity to meet a given requirement of stop band rejection and passband ripple is driven by the length of the transition band relative to Nyquist.

Consider the filter as being completely circular in that we can rotate the response in frequency to any other location in the digital bandwidth from $-f_s/2$ to $+f_s/2$. Thus the requirement to have a passband extending to $+f_s/2$ and then a stop band starting at $-f_s/2$ has a transition band of zero. Thus it is not possible to both extend the positive frequency response to Nyquist AND have rejection at negative Nyquist frequency.

A finite transition bandwidth is needed to avoid the impossible requirement for an infinite length filter. If this is not acceptable and It is possible to resample to a higher rate, then signal occupying each of those frequencies can then be passed and rejected as desired as they will no longer be in vicinity of each other at the Nyquist boundary.